# multiple definition of node xi1[1,1]

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution

i have a problem in the code below the problem is occured in compiling process " multiple definition of node  xi1[1,1]", anyone help me to solve this problem please.
many thanks in advance

```
model {  
for(i in 1:N){ 
#measurement equation model 
for(j in 1:P){y[i,j]~dnorm(mu[i,j],psi[j])I(thd[j,z[i,j]],thd[j,z[i,j]+1])} 
xi[i,1]<-mu[i,1]+lam[1]*mu[i,2]+lam[2]*mu[i,3]+lam[3]*mu[i,4]+lam[4]*mu[i,5]+lam[5]*mu[i,6]
xi[i,2]<-mu[i,1]+lam[1]*mu[i,2]+lam[2]*mu[i,3]+lam[3]*mu[i,4]+lam[4]*mu[i,5]+lam[5]*mu[i,6]+xi[i,1]
#structural equation model 
xi[i,1:2]~dmnorm(zero2[1:2],phi[1:2,1:2]) 
eta[i]~dnorm(nu[i],psd1) 
nu[i]<-gam[1]*xi[i,1]
mu[i,1:6]~dnorm(0.8,4.0) 
}# end of i
for(i in 1:2){zero2[i]<-0.0} 
#priors on loadings and coefficients 
for(i in 1:5){lam[i]~dnorm(0.8,4.0)} 
for(i in 1:1){gam[i]~dnorm(0.6,4.0)} 
#priors on precisions 
for(j in 1:P){ 
psi[j]~dgamma(10,8) 
sgm[j]<-1/psi[j]} 
psd~dgamma(10,8) 
sgd<-1/psd
phi[1:2,1:2]~dwish(R[1:2,1:2], 30) 
phx[1:2,1:2]<-inverse(phi[1:2,1:2]) 
} #end of model
```

Answer (score 0):

You have these two lines:

```
xi[i,1]<-mu[i,1]+lam[1]*mu[i,2]+lam[2]*mu[i,3]+lam[3]*mu[i,4]+lam[4]*mu[i,5]+lam[5]*mu[i,6]
...
xi[i,1:2]~dmnorm(zero2[1:2],phi[1:2,1:2])
```

Since both are in the i loop, you have defined xi[1,1] twice: once as a deterministic quantity and once as a random variable (data?).

Comment: thank you so much for your response, what should i do now if i delete the second definition of xi[i,1:2] the error will be "expected multivariate node" so i cannot delete any of them. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the error now is  "expected multivariate node"  without delete any of them.